# Crystal Report Viewer

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, vb6

Previously I use vb6 with crystal report and i use the crystal report viewer with vb6 to preview the report.

now i moved to vb.net 2010 where i cannot find the crystal report viewer Activex control? i specially want to use crystal report Activex viewer in dot.net because it will allow the user to edit the report as user has need,

if the crystal report activex viewer cannot support then give me way to modify the crystal report file after the exe has been build in vb.net 2010?

Answer (score 1):

.NET uses .Net DLLs, not Active X controls.   When in .Net Studio...you will be looking for the DLL's that support run time operations...NOT an ActiveX.    Dig back into your documentation and samples...it should be covered there.

Answer (score 0):

As Juan said you need to look for .Net DLLs in order to use CrystalReportViewer. 
From your question I am assuming you already have installed Crystal Report 13 for Visual Studio 2010. If you haven't https://www.sap.com/india/products/crystal-visual-studio.html this is the link from where you can download it.
Now coming to your question of not being able to find dll of CrystalReportViewer You need to follow these steps:

1. First in your menu bar go to project and go to properties of the project.
2. Go to Compile section, then to advanced compile options.
3. Go to Target Framework by default it will be on ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile" set it to ".NET Framework 4".
4. Restart your Visual Studio.

Voila you can see it.

Link to download .net Framework 4
https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=17718

Mark it as Accepted Answer if it works for you.